# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/FacesException

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

I am trying to run JSF project with tomcat and eclipse.

I have just implemented simple page with HelloWorld. When I try to start server its throwing following error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@2fbb7466
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/FacesException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2793)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have included following libraries in classpath:

- javae-api-6.0.jar
- javae-web-api-6.0.jar
- javax-servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
- jsf-api-2.1.jar
- jsf-impl-1.2.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar
- primefaces-5.0.jar

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Look[here](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/18856.page#sthash.P5r1w19h.dpbs). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jens yes it helped me. See my answer for details. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis, I found that I have added libraries from wrong place. I have also removed extra libraries from build path.

Following is the final list of dependency and it worked for me:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.